# JFace close dialog in SelectionListener

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface, wizard

How do I close a `Dialog` in a `SelectionListener`? Currently my `SelectionListener` looks like this:

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getService(ICommandService.class);
    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getService(IHandlerService.class);

    Command command = commandService
            .getCommand("com.mainfirst.backoffice.gui.accounting.command.createBookingReversal");

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("com.mainfirst.backoffice.gui.accounting.reversalCodeParameter",
            String.valueOf(model.getVal().getCode()));

    ParameterizedCommand paraCommand = ParameterizedCommand.generateCommand(command, params);

    try {
        handlerService.executeCommand(paraCommand, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Status status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, AccountingActivator.PLUGIN_ID,
                "Error opening reversal wizard", ex);
        StatusManager.getManager().handle(status, StatusManager.SHOW);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    close();
}
```

As you can see I do call `close();`, but the `Dialog` does stay open in the end. Moving the call inside a `finally` block doesn't help either. My command opens a new `Wizard` in front of the `Dialog`. Might I have to close the `Dialog` before the `Wizard` opens?

Comment: @greg-449 edited the question. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113246/jface-disable-finish-button-in-wizard) is my second question

Comment: What does the command do? Are you expecting the dialog to close before the command ends (it won't)?

Comment: the command calls the handler which in turn only opens the wizard. i do expect the dialog to close as soon as the button is clicked, but the command should still be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the dialog to close before the command it is running completes you will need to run the command asynchronously. Use `Display.asyncExec` for this. Use something like:

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() ->
       {
          ... code to call command
       });

    close();
}
```

(assuming Java 8, use a `Runnable` for Java 7 or earlier).